# Recursively search Properties in class decorated by attribute

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, reflection, attributes

I would like to get all properties decorated by attribute AggregateAuthorizeIdentifier. It is core functionallity, so should be as fast as posible.

I can search recurvicvely via all properties but I would check all System and 3rd parties libs. But it isn't optimal solution.

Have you met with such a problem?

```
public class ReadOrderHistoryQuery
{
    public List<string> Ordering { get; set; }

    public Criteria Criteria { get; set; }

    public class Criteria
    {
        [AggregateAuthorizeIdentifier]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my solution:

```
    static IEnumerable<PropertyWithAttribute> GetAuthorizeIdentifierAttribute(object command)
    {
        var attributedProperties = GetAuthorizeIdentifierAttribute(command.GetType());
        return attributedProperties;
    }
    static IEnumerable<PropertyWithAttribute> GetAuthorizeIdentifierAttribute(Type type)
    {
        //check current property
        var result = type.GetProperties()
            .Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(AggregateAuthorizeIdentifierAttribute)))
            .Select(p => new PropertyWithAttribute()
            {
                Property = p,
                Attribute = p.GetCustomAttribute<AggregateAuthorizeIdentifierAttribute>(true)
            })
            .ToList();
        //deeper check all properties
        result.AddRange(type.GetProperties()
            .SelectMany(p => GetAuthorizeIdentifierAttribute(p.PropertyType)));
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `But it isn't optimal solution.` why do you think that?

Comment: My solution search via all System properties, like String, List, etc. and 3rd parties. It is quite unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly I achived it with additional type selector (by string).

```
    const string PropertyTypeStartWithSelector = "Diabdis.";

    static IEnumerable<PropertyWithAttribute> GetAuthorizeIdentifierAttribute(Type type, string propertyPathPrefix)
    {
        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        //check current property
        var result = properties
            .Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(AggregateAuthorizeIdentifierAttribute)))
            .Select(p => new PropertyWithAttribute()
            {
                PropertyPath = propertyPathPrefix == null ? p.Name : $"{propertyPathPrefix}{PropertyPathSeparator}{p.Name}",
                Attribute = p.GetCustomAttribute<AggregateAuthorizeIdentifierAttribute>(true)
            })
            .ToList();

        //check deeper properties, BUT just selector classes
        result.AddRange(properties
            .Where(p => p.DeclaringType.FullName.StartsWith(PropertyTypeStartWithSelector))
            .SelectMany(p => GetAuthorizeIdentifierAttribute(p.PropertyType, propertyPathPrefix == null ? p.Name : $"{propertyPathPrefix}{PropertyPathSeparator}{p.Name}")));
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do something like that, I always do it like this :

```
object objectToSearch = ...

PropertyInfo[] properties = objectToSearch.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (properties != null && properties.Length > 0)
{
    properties.ToList().ForEach(p =>
    {
        if (p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AggregateAuthorizeIdentifierAttribute), false).Count() == 1)
        {
            // Do something with the property
        }
    });
}
```

According to that, you can make an extension method to return all the properties of an object that has a specific attribute

Comment: Binding is useful, but does not solve problem with searching within System module (like List, Dictrionaries, etc.)